# Pager information not showing up in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is a fairly embarrassing question.
I have jQuery populating my jqGrid.  But I can't seem to get it to populate the pager part.
Here is a sample JSON response:

```
{"ROWS":[["",XXX,"XYZ","XYZ","",""],"PAGE":1.0,"RECORDS":2421,"TOTAL":243.0}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Finally, some of the JS

```
            pager: '#pager',
              jsonReader: {
                root: "ROWS", 
                page: "PAGE", 
                total: "TOTAL", 
                records:"RECORDS", 
                cell: "", 
                id: "0" 
                }
```

I feel like I am doing something very simple, but simply wrong.  Another set of eyes on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? In many last version you can use HTML like `<table id="list"></table><div id="pager"></div>` without any additional attributes.

Comment: To @Oleg point, the grid pager displays with this HTML element declaration:

    <table id="list"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>

but not this:

    <table id="list" />
    <div id="pager" />

though the two are, I believe, semantically equivalent.

Comment: @CraigBoland: No, what I mean is that one don't need to include `class="scroll"` part as the attributes of `<table>` and `<div>`. Very old previous versions of jqGrid required that. In the same way the attributes `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` and `style="text-align:center;"` are not needed. It's what I wanted to say in my old comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what, I made the mistake of overriding the JSON variables earlier in the query.  My advice is take out all extraneous stuff and you will be surprised at how much the grid does for you.  Then hack it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that use use `loadonce:true` option. It follow that after the data are loaded the `datatype:'local'` will be set. The values from the pager will be used in the case corresponds to the local data.

Comment: That didn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: @user573172: Could you append your question with the jqGrid definition?